# Memory Overflow? std::badalloc

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a program that solves generally for 1D brownian motion using an Euler's Method.
Being a stochastic process, I want to average it over many particles. But I find that as I ramp up the number of particles, it overloads and i get the *std::badalloc* error, which I understand is a memory error.

Here is my full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

// Box-Muller Method to generate gaussian numbers
double generateGaussianNoise(double mu, double sigma) {
    const double epsilon = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
    const double tau = 2.0 * 3.14159265358979323846;

    static double z0, z1;
    static bool generate;
    generate = !generate;

    if (!generate) return z1 * sigma + mu;

    double u1, u2;
    do {
        u1 = rand() * (1.0 / RAND_MAX);
        u2 = rand() * (1.0 / RAND_MAX);
    } while (u1 <= epsilon);

    z0 = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u1)) * cos(tau * u2);
    z1 = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u1)) * sin(tau * u2);
    return z0 * sigma + mu;
}

int main() {
    // Initialize Variables
    double gg;  // Gaussian Number Picked  from distribution

    // Integrator
    double t0 = 0;  // Setting the Time Window
    double tf = 10;
    double n = 5000;           // Number of Steps
    double h = (tf - t0) / n;  // Time Step Size

    // Set Constants
    const double pii = atan(1) * 4;  // pi
    const double eta = 1;            // viscous constant
    const double m = 1;              // mass
    const double aa = 1;             // radius
    const double Temp = 30;          // Temperature in Kelvins
    const double KB = 1;             // Boltzmann Constant
    const double alpha = (6 * pii * eta * aa);

    // More Constants
    const double mu = 0;  // Gaussian Mean
    const double sigma = 1;  // Gaussian Std Deviation
    const double ng = n;  // No. of pts to generate for Gauss distribution
    const double npart = 1000;  // No. of Particles

    // Initial Conditions
    double x0 = 0;
    double y0 = 0;
    double t = t0;
    // Vectors
    vector<double> storX;  // Vector that keeps displacement values
    vector<double> storY;  // Vector that keeps velocity values

    vector<double> storT;  // Vector to store time
    vector<double> storeGaussian;  // Vector to store Gaussian numbers generated

    vector<double> holder;  // Placeholder Vector for calculation   operations
    vector<double> mainstore;  // Vector that holds the final value desired

    storT.push_back(t0);

    // Prepares mainstore
    for (int z = 0; z < (n+1); z++) {
        mainstore.push_back(0);
    }

    for (int NN = 0; NN < npart; NN++) {
        holder.clear();
        storX.clear();
        storY.clear();
        storT.clear();
        storT.push_back(0);

        // Prepares holder
        for (int z = 0; z < (n+1); z++) {
            holder.push_back(0);

            storX.push_back(0);

            storY.push_back(0);
        }

        // Gaussian Generator
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (double iiii = 0; iiii < ng; iiii++) {
            gg = generateGaussianNoise(0, 1);  // generateGaussianNoise(mu,sigma)
            storeGaussian.push_back(gg);
        }

        // Solver
        for (int ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
            storY[ii + 1] =
                storY[ii] - (alpha / m) * storY[ii] * h +
                (sqrt(2 * alpha * KB * Temp) / m) * sqrt(h) * storeGaussian[ii];
            storX[ii + 1] = storX[ii] + storY[ii] * h;
            holder[ii + 1] =
                pow(storX[ii + 1], 2);  // Finds the displacement squared

            t = t + h;
            storT.push_back(t);
        }

        // Updates the Main Storage
        for (int z = 0; z < storX.size(); z++) {
            mainstore[z] = mainstore[z] + holder[z];
        }
    }

    // Average over the number of particles
    for (int z = 0; z < storX.size(); z++) {
        mainstore[z] = mainstore[z] / (npart);
    }

    // Outputs the data
    ofstream fout("LangevinEulerTest.txt");
    for (int jj = 0; jj < storX.size(); jj++) {
        fout << storT[jj] << '\t' << mainstore[jj] << '\t' << storX[jj] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, *npart* is the variable that I change to vary the number of particles. But after each iteration, I do clear my storage vectors like ***storX,storY..***. So on paper, the number of particles should not affect memory? I am only just calling the compiler to repeat many more times, and add onto the main storage vector ***mainstore***. I am running my code on a computer with 4GB ram.

Would greatly appreciate it if anyone could point out my errors in logic or suggest improvements.

**Edit**: Currently the number of particles is set to npart = 1000.
So when I try to ramp it up to like npart = 20000 or npart = 50000, it gives me memory errors.

**Edit2** I've edited the code to allocate an extra index to each of the storage vectors. But it does not seem to fix the memory overflow

Comment: Could you spend some time indenting your code properly, please? You'll get more people looking at it if it's easier to read.

Comment: my apologies. so you suggest I should break up the sections, so it isnt one long chunk?

Comment: @CandyMan I just fixed the indenting in your code. It seems to work well though.

Comment: @REACHUS ah thanks, i see what you mean. I'll keep that in mind the next time. As for the number of particles (**npart**), I tried ramping it up to 10,000 or 50,000. which crashes the thing. So I'm not so sure on this part

Comment: @CandyMan: Have you passed this program over `valgrind` or anything?

Comment: Valgrind also doesn't report anything worrisome when npart=1000.

Comment: @KemyLand I have not heard of valgrind before, but I'm looking at it now!

Comment: Your solver loop accesses the vectors out of bounds in the last iteration. That could very well cause a bad_alloc at a later point in time.

Comment: `==27955== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27955== Command: ./c
==27955== 
==27955== 
==27955== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27955==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27955==   total heap usage: 96 allocs, 96 frees, 134,881,800 bytes allocated
==27955== 
==27955== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27955== 
==27955== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27955== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)`

Comment: @ComicSansMS: Valgrind says otherwise...

Comment: Ran the program on my machine with `npart = 10000` and it didn't crashed (I have 2GB RAM, BTW). Maybe you have too little RAM? Passing this by Valgrind now!

Comment: @KemyLand Well, I don't need valgrind to see that `storY[n]` on a vector with `n` elements is out-of-bounds.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: But I don't see how does an off-by-one error may throw `std::bad_alloc` instead of `std::out_of_range`... The standard doesn't mandates this, but it's not too logical from a library implementator's point of view.

Comment: @KemyLand Accessing using `vector[x]` doesn't do range-checks, you need `vector.at(x)` for that. So you'll corrupt memory and that can cause anything.

Comment: Not the cause of the problem, but you should not call srand in a loop, only once at startup!

Comment: @KemyLand The standard mandates undefined behavior, which can very well lead to a `bad_alloc` in this case (or demons flying out of your nostrils, but I guess the Op just got lucky here).

Comment: @ComicSansMS: That's what I meant, the standard doesn't mandates anything, but it's still nonsense anyway for the library to throw `std::bad_alloc`...

Comment: @Martin C: Depends on your runtime. I use visual studio and it does when debugging.

Comment: @WernerHenze: Why should you?

Comment: @Gombat it is allowed to do runtime checks for `operator[]`, since the standard indicates that `Portable programs should never call this function with an argument n that is out of range, since this causes undefined behavior.`. `vector::at` _needs_ to be range-checked. The unchecked variant can do whatever it wants when being called out-of-range.

Comment: @WernerHenze I think call srand in the loop because I want the gaussian points generated for each different particle to be different. So do you mean that actually by putting it outside, it doesn't make a difference?

Comment: @CandyMan You can call srand in the loop, but it does not make sense. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519965/c-program-srand and other answers on SO when you search for "srand".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an out of bounds exception in the solver part. `storY` has size n and you access `ii+1` where i goes up to `n-1`. So for your code provided. `storY` has size 5000. It is allowed to access with indices between 0 and 4999 (including) but you try to access with index 5000. The same for `storX`, `holder` and `mainstore`.

Also, `storeGaussian` does not get cleared before adding new variables. It grows by n for each npart loop. You access only the first `n` values of it in the solver part anyway.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that (also @ComicSansMS). I have now allocated a size of 5001 for `storY`, `storX` and `holder`, but the `std::badalloc` error is still persistent for say `npart = 20000`

Comment: Yeah, I missed `holder`, but `mainstore` is one too small, too. If I resize them all to one bigger, I get no memory leaks or bad_allocs.

Comment: Ah yes, regarding `mainstore` I meant to type that in the earlier comment too. Just to be sure that I am thinking the same thing as you do, I would just change the loops that sizes them to something like `for (int z = 0; z < (n+1); z++)` right?  - I did that and am still getting memory errors!

Comment: Yes, if that way, specified variables have size n+1, we talk about the same thing. But -> Is it right, that `storeGaussian` never get's cleared? In the solver part, you acces the first n values, but in the gaussian generator part, you add new values to the end. Setting n to 500000 has let me reproduce your error and clearing `storeGaussian` in front of the the gaussian generator for loop resolved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please note, that `vector::clear` removes all elements from the vector, but does not necessarily change the vector's capacity (i.e. it's storage array), see the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/).

This won't cause the problem here, because you'll reuse the same array in the next runs, but it's something to be aware when using vectors.